# Spqrk SQL - How to use coalesce on window sum result

Tags: apache-spark-sql

## Question

Please help understand the error from the Spark SQL.

> Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
>   Message: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'f.`passengerId`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(sum(CAST(f.`count` AS BIGINT)) AS `_w0`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'f.`passengerId`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.

#### SQL

```
SELECT 
    f.*,
    coalesce(sum(count), 0) OVER (   -- Without coalesce, no issue
        PARTITION BY passengerId 
        ORDER BY 
            passengerId ASC, 
            date DESC
        ROWS BETWEEN 
            UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
            AND 
            1 PRECEDING
    ) as num_flights
FROM
    flightData f
ORDER BY 
    passengerId, date
```

## Background

Without coalesce, the result includes null for sum(count) and would like to simply replace it with 0.

Comment: can you please sum sample data for same